# redirect to action in void function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

If I have

```
public ActionResult Join(int? id)
{
   if (id == null)
   {
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }

   return View();
}
```

It works well. How can I make this code reusable? I must call it in many actions.
I've tried this:

```
public ActionResult Join(int? id)
{
    isNull(id);

    return View();
}

public void isNull(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

But it doesn't redirect.

Comment: RedirectToAction("Index") has to be returned in Join, which means IsNull would need to return it also, making it somewhat redundant. I think your best bet is just to stick with If(id == null) return RedirectToAction("Index"), there's not enough complexity there to deserve a separate method for it in my opinion.

Comment: as far i believe you cannot use `RedirectToAction` without return type (ActionResult) .

Comment: What you have is fine. Abstracting it out doesn't seem like a good idea here (but see some of the answers for working if somewhat convoluted solutions)

Answer (score 2):

You could do some functional programming:

```
protected ActionResult WithID(int? arg, Func<int, ActionResult> logic)
{
  if (arg == null)
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

  return logic(arg.Value);
}
```

invoked like this:

```
public ActionResult Join(int? arg)
{
  return WithID(arg, (id) => 
  {
    return View();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `Join` action requires `id`, then don't make `id` nullable:

```
public ActionResult Join(int id)
{
   // use id

   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to return your function early, in a different function. That is impossible. That is not to say that taking out the `IsNull` is impossible, but rather impractical. A possible solution could be

```
public ActionResult isNull(int? id, Func<ActionResult> _else) {
  if (id == null) {
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  } else {
    return _else();
  }
}
```

which could be called like

```
public ActionResult Join(int? id){
  Func<ActionResult> ifNotNull = () => {
    //do whatever you want here, in your case
    return View();
  }
  return isNull(id, ifNotNull);
}
```

or directly

```
public ActionResult Join(int? id){
  return isNull(id, () => View());
}
```

Whether this is a good idea is a different question.

You will probably want to use Id in it though, so you'll get something like

```
public ActionResult isNull(int? id, Func<int, ActionResult> _else) {
      if (id == null) {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
      } else {
        return _else(id.value);
      }
}
```

You could abstract that out further to

```
public ActionResult isNull<T>(T id, Func<T, ActionResult> _else) where T: class {
      if (id == null) {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
      } else {
        return _else(id);
      }
}
```

and

```
public ActionResult isNull<T>(Nullable<T> id, Func<T, ActionResult> _else) {
      if (id == null) {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
      } else {
        return _else(id.value);
      }
}
```

but by now, we definitely have left the realm of good ideas.

Answer (score -1):

The second method is not returning ActionResult. make `void` to Action result and **return RedirectToAction**

Comment: ok I've made it. BUT if this id will not null what to return in this action? view? it'll wrong

Comment: You're adding complexity where it isn't needed. Stick with what you had originally, as you'll always have to make a comparison against what IsNull() returns to decide whether to return it or not in Join(), meaning another If will be required. 
Your best bet is to just stick with the original if (id == null), instead of turning it into if(IsNull(id)).